# Xamarin.Forms - Pass a value from View to ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

Anyone know how to pass a random string value to the viewmodel from within the view's code-behind in Xamarin.Forms?

1. The string value doesn't come from any of the controls being displayed to the user.
2. The value is not available until well after the page is displayed to the user.
3. The value is only available to me to consume from within the view, not the viewmodel.

Comment: `((ViewModelType)this.BindingContext).SomeProperty = "someRandomString"`

Comment: @woelliJ I just knew someone would respond back with some custom class that implements some IOBservable<IDONTUNDERSTAND> crap.  Thank you sir!

Comment: excuse me? There is the `BindingContext` - which ever< Xamarin.Forms View has. That is being cast to the Type your ViewModel is (so you can access its properties) and then there is a simple Property `SomeProperty` which is set to your string. sorry, i assumed you knew about said things because you mentioned MVVM. (all of these are part of MVVM in xamarin forms). you didn't provide any code to build an answer upon. i didn't mean to be disrespectful.

Comment: show some code what really you want to do.

Comment: @woelliJ Don't you just love text, lol.  The answer you gave was exactly what I needed, you misunderstood what I was saying.  I would mark your answer as the answer but it's not listed as one.

Comment: ah haha. i thought you were being cynical ;) i'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by accessing your `ViewModel` through the `BindingContext` of your `View` like so:

```
((ViewModelType)this.BindingContext).SomeProperty = "someRandomString"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could just make a property or a method on the view model to accept the value.

```
public string APropertyToSet {get; set;}
public void SetSomeValueFromTheView(object value) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe MessagingCenter concept will useful for you

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from WoeliJ's answer, for those who want to pass a button parameter from view to viewmodel. In the sample below, I'm passing a button text to some variable in the view model.

```
private void *Clicked Event* (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ((*YourViewModel*)this.BindingContext).*SomeVarInViewModel* = ((Button)sender).Text as string;
}
```